# Ruby regex for extracting email addresses not detecting hypens

Tags: regex

Tried looking at the regex that some others are using, but for some reason it's not working for me.

I just basically have a string, such as "testing-user@example.com", It'll only extract user@example.com and not the whole thing.

Here's what I have:

```
regex = Regexp.new(/\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-,]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b/)
email = line.scan(regex)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `+-,` matches all the chars which are in the range from `+` to `,`

Comment: Which happens to be only `+` and `,` as they follow each other in the ASCII codes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyphen needs to be escaped for the position it is at inside of the character class.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+\-,]+
              ^
```

(`+-,`) currently matches a single character in the **range** between `+` and `,`

Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special** meaning. You can place the hyphen as the first or last character of the class. In some regex implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to precede it with a backslash it in order to add it to your class.

Comment: I tried escaping it but I ended up getting another error trying to parse another email address.

Comment: It doesn't get parsed by the "regex = ..." line. Here's the error: /root/scripts/test.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': empty range in char class: /\sAnn\s(.*?)\s["another.user-test@example.com"]/m (RegexpError)

Comment: Your error is `["another.user-test@example.com"]`. You can't use an email address like this inside of `[` `]`

Comment: Gotcha. I think that's coming from another regex that I have. Thanks so much for your help. If this solves it, then I think I should be fine trying to work out the other issue. Thanks again.